# database restoration fails with an error

Tags: c#, vb.net

i am using the following code snippet to backup/restore database

Backup works fine but when i try to restore i get this error

***"RESTORE cannot process database 'LIC' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally."***

```
If strAction = Action.BackUp Then

            strQuery = "BACKUP DATABASE LIC to disk='C:\Backup\ICLS.bak'"
        Else

            strQuery = "RESTORE DATABASE LIC FROM disk='C:\Backup\ICLS.bak'"

        End If

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Restore Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message says, you are connected to the database you're trying to restore.  Change your connection string to use the Master database and then restore.

Comment: What do you mean by master datbase??

Comment: There will be a database called "Master" on the server.  Connect to it instead of LIC

Comment: File "LIC" cannot be restored over the existing "D:\2008VS\Templates\Demos\BackUpAndRestoreSQLDB\bin\Debug/LIC.mdf ". Reissue the RESTORE statement using WITH REPLACE to overwrite pre-existing files, or WITH MOVE to identify an alternate location. File "LIC_log" cannot be restored over the existing "D:\2008VS\Templates\Demos\BackUpAndRestoreSQLDB\bin\Debug/LIC_Log.ldf". Reissue the RESTORE statement using WITH REPLACE to overwrite pre-existing files, or WITH MOVE to identify an alternate location. Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement.

Comment: Is that a question? Add WIITH REPLACE to your SQL to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: Sorry :(...Just a last question...when i backup my DB for the first time..Its about 1.8 MB...but every time i backup the DB the size of the backup file(.bak) increases....why??I am not inserting any data into the DB...but still the backup size increases on every backup.NOTE:Size of backup file increases only if the .bak file is present in the folder..if not present the first backup file size is 1.8MB.

Comment: Don't know. I would ask that as a separate question.